# Как ограничить кол-во вводимых символов в JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Подскажите, как ограничить кол-во вводимых символов в `JTextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выриант можно прослушать события нажатия кнопки и игнорировать его если он приведет к увеличению размера текста.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int limit=5;
        final TextField textfield=new TextField();

        textfield.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                if(textfield.getText().length()>=limit &&
                        evt.getKeyChar()!= KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE &&
                        evt.getKeyChar()== KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)
                    evt.consume();

            }
        });
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.add(textfield);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```